# Как в Windows добавить на C# программу в список установленных?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop

Всем привет!

Пишу на WPF свой инсталлятор. Соответственно, в инсталляторе необходима функциональность добавления программы в список установленных. Понимаю, что по всей видимости необходимо использовать классы из пространства именно System.Management или же необходимо делать записи в реестр Windows другим способом. В общем, интересует как лучше это делать, как добавить ссылку на деинсталлятор, который является инсталлятором, но должен вызываться с параметром, и вообще все что с этим связано, в т.ч. подводные камни, рифы и скалы.

Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше использовать готовые инстументы

Answer (score 1):

Вы изобретаете велосипед. Возьмите тот же WixSharp: https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp - в него можно добавить свой UI (в т.ч. на WPF), но при этом будет использоваться стандартный функционал WiX.

Comment: Как это отвечает на поставленный вопрос? Это больше на комментарий похоже, а не на ответ. Вот я допустим писал свой установщик для одной игры, ибо там такие дебри надо было реализовать, которые любой стандартный инструментарий не даст в полной мере. Не забывайте, что у всех свои задачи, и бывают случаи, где написать свое намного проще и лучше, чем использовать что-то готовое!